# how to create dictionary with new keys and values and also add values to one key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want put a list of tuples into a dictionary like this:
what i want to do is to add keys with multiple values dynamically.

The list of tuples:

```
[((1.0, 54, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((0.0, 55, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((0.0, 26, 0.0), 'less'),
.
.
.
 ((1.0, 40, 0.0), 'more'),
 ((1.0, 25, 1.0), 'less'),]
```

The output should be like this:

the labels should be the keys and  the tuples of data_points should be the values
i want to create the dict so that the keys won't be repeated

```
{'less': [(1.0, 54, 0.0), (0.0, 55, 0.0), (0.0, 26, 0.0), (1.0, 25, 1.0), (0.0, 15, 0.0), (0.0, 35, 0.0), (0.0, 41, 0.0), (0.0, 20, 0.0), (1.0, 18, 1.0)],   \
'more': [(1.0, 40, 0.0), (0.0, 13, 1.0), (0.0, 50, 1.0), (1.0, 33, 0.0), (1.0, 30, 1.0), (0.0, 39, 1.0), (1.0, 55, 0.0)]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
data = [((1.0, 54, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((0.0, 55, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((0.0, 26, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((1.0, 40, 0.0), 'more'),
 ((1.0, 25, 1.0), 'less')]

result = {}
for value, key in data:
       result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(result)
```

Or as an alternative, you could check if the key do not exists in the dictionary and set the corresponding value to the empty list:

```
data = [((1.0, 54, 0.0), 'less'),
        ((0.0, 55, 0.0), 'less'),
        ((0.0, 26, 0.0), 'less'),
        ((1.0, 40, 0.0), 'more'),
        ((1.0, 25, 1.0), 'less')]

result = {}
for value, key in data:
    if key not in result:
        result[key] = []
    result[key].append(value)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'less': [(1.0, 54, 0.0), (0.0, 55, 0.0), (0.0, 26, 0.0), (1.0, 25, 1.0)], 'more': [(1.0, 40, 0.0)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.append` is fine for this.

```
out_dict = {'less':[], 'more':[]}
for t in list_of_tuples:
    out_dict[t[1]].append(t[0])
```

If you don't want to define keys ahead of time:

```
out_dict = {}
for t in list_of_tuples:
    if t[1] not in out_dict:
        out_dict[t[1]] = []
    out_dict[t[1]].append(t[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting each tuple into the right list within the dict.

```
 a = [((1.0, 54, 0.0), 'less'),
     ((0.0, 55, 0.0), 'less'),
     ((0.0, 26, 0.0), 'less'),
     ((1.0, 40, 0.0), 'more'),
     ((1.0, 25, 1.0), 'less')]

mydict = {'less': list(), 'more': list()}

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][1] == 'less':
        mydict['less'].append(a[i][0])
    else:
        mydict['more'].append(a[i][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more general purpose solution I'd recommend using a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
# Assuming your list is in a variable called 'data'
for data_tuple in data:
    result[data_tuple[1]].append(data_tuple[0])
```

When a key is given to a defaultdict that does not exist, it will call the factory function you provide (in this case just `list`).

Answer (score 0):

use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
data = [((1.0, 54, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((0.0, 55, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((0.0, 26, 0.0), 'less'),
 ((1.0, 40, 0.0), 'more'),
 ((1.0, 25, 1.0), 'less')]

from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for value, key in data:
    result[key].append(value)

print(result)
```